# Does spark on mesos support data locality?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mesos

Does spark on mesos support data locality? Assume mesos agents  run on datanode.

Comment: The Spark UI tells you the locality of the tasks

Answer (score 1):

Data locality support doesn't depend on the cluster manager at all. It depends only on the source of the data. So if you talk about HDFS datanode then the answer is positive - it does support data locality.